# async Task<String> not return correct result,WebClient.OpenReadTaskAsync()

Tags: c#, .net

in winform program(C#)，async Task not return correct result，my codes are below：

```
public async void method1()
{
    await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
            if (textBox1.InvokeRequired)
            {
                textBox1.Invoke(new Action(() => textBox1.Text += "AAAAAAAAAAAA\r\n"));
            }
        });

    if(textBox1.InvokeRequired)
    {
        textBox1.Invoke(new Action(() => textBox1.Text += "BBBBBBBBBB\r\n"));
    }
}

public async Task<string> method2()
{
    string result = string.Empty;
    System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient();
    Stream st = await wc.OpenReadTaskAsync("https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443(v=vs.110).aspx#What Happens in an Async Method");
    //Task<Stream> st= wc.OpenReadTaskAsync("https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443(v=vs.110).aspx#What Happens in an Async Method");
    //Stream st2 = st.Result;
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(st);
    result = sr.ReadToEnd();

    return result;
}
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Text += method2()+"\r\n";

    method1();
    textBox1.Text += "CCCCCCCCCCCC\r\n";
}
```

### Output:

System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.String]

CCCCCCCCCCCC

AAAAAAAAAAAA

### My question:

1)method2,i want to return the page content,but in fact,it is "System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.String]"

2)string "BBBBBBBBBB" not been added in textBox1,is this why?

Comment: Your methods are async, so you need to `await` the result. Your line of code here: `method2()+"\r\n";` is calling `ToString()` on a `Task<string>`. You need to await both method calls to get the result you're expecting.

Comment: Excuse me,where should "await" be palced?thank you.
I trying such code:
    Task<Stream> st= wc.OpenReadTaskAsync("https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443(v=vs.110).aspx#What Happens in an Async Method");
Stream st2 = await st.Result;

Then,a exception is throw:can not waiting

Comment: In `button1_Click` the code should be something like: `var method2result = await method2(); textBox1.Text += method2result+"\r\n";. You'll also need to mark the method as async. `method1` does not need to be async at all, and is actually incorrect. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/142003) for the correct implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Here you have the code with some changes (textBox for richTextBox) and some clarifications.

*string "BBBBBBBBBB" not been added in textBox1,is this why?*

InvokeRequired only return true if you call it from a worker thread.

*method2,i want to return the page content,but in fact,it is "System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.String]"*

Since method1 return Task you have few options, call method.result (not recommende, it will block the main thread) or use async/await to get the result.

```
    public async void method1()
    {
        await Task.Run(() =>
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
            if (richTextBox1.InvokeRequired)
            {
                richTextBox1.Invoke(new Action(() => richTextBox1.Text += "AAAAAAAAAAAA\r\n"));
            }
        });

        //This in main thread so InvokeRequired == false
        //if (textBox1.InvokeRequired)
        //{
        //    textBox1.Invoke(new Action(() => textBox1.Text += "BBBBBBBBBB\r\n"));
        //}            
        richTextBox1.Text += "BBBBBBBBBB\r\n";
    }

    public async Task<string> method2()
    {
        string result = string.Empty;
        System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient();
        var st = await wc.OpenReadTaskAsync("https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443(v=vs.110).aspx#What Happens in an Async Method");
        //Task<Stream> st= wc.OpenReadTaskAsync("https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443(v=vs.110).aspx#What Happens in an Async Method");
        //Stream st2 = st.Result;
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(st);
        result = sr.ReadToEnd();

        return result;
    }
    private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //await is needed to get string insted of Task<string>
        richTextBox1.Text = await method2(); 

        method1();
        richTextBox1.Text += "CCCCCCCCCCCC\r\n";
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Change your button click event like this

```
private async void Button_Click..
```

Replace

```
textBox1.Text += method2()+"\r\n";
```

To

```
textBox1.Text += await method2()+"\r\n";
```

Comment: After this change,run the program,Form is stuck